# cygwin1.dll is missing - Cannot run program

Tags: c++, c, dll, cygwin

I wrote a program in C/C++ and compiled it using Cygwin. When I ran the compiled file, I receive an error about a missing library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cygwin is like a simple framework: With every program you build you have to include the library `cygwin1.dll`.

**Important note**: Downloading the library online might be risky as it can be a virus.

To fix the issue:
 1. **Go to your cygwin directory.** Usually that is `C:\cygwin` or `C:\cygwin64`.
  If you don't know where cygwin is, download the [setup file](http://www.cygwin.com/install.html) and run it. The installation path the installer suggests is the Cygwin installation location.

*Tip: Don't use a directory to put cygwin in that includes spaces (" ") as it will be easier to run programs with command-line parameters.*
 2. **Copy the file.** It should be in `<Drive>:\cygwin\bin\cygwin1.dll`.
 3. **Copy the file to your program folder**, the same directory as your exe file.

Your program should run without throwing an exception.